# Obtaining a JFrame from a JApplet

Tags: java, swing, applet, jframe

Given a JApplet, how do I obtain the JFrame object corresponding to this applet?

```
JApplet applet = this;
JRootPane rootPane = getRootPane();
Container contentPane = getContentPane();
JFrame jframe = ...; // How do I obtain the JFrame?
```

Comment: trying to run an applet inside a JFrame?

Comment: Omry: No, I have code that assumes access to a JFrame. I want this JFrame to be the "JApplet window". Creating a new JFrame won't work since that will create a new window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new JFrame from an Applet. But there is no container like a JFrame surrounding an Applet. The Applet *is* ths container.

Comment: IIRC, the plug-in does have an embedded `JFrame`, but this is just an implementation detail. `Applet` is considered the *top-level* container.